# Prevent default "close editor" behavior of going to previously opened editor

Tags: visual-studio-code

When closing an editor/tab in VSCode, it navigates back to the previous editor/tab you were in. Compare to Firefox or Chrome, which simply go to the next tab to the right.

This is annoying, because it depends on hidden state. I would prefer a setting that depends on the horizontal locations of the tabs, which is more predictable.

Is there a setting to prevent this default behavior, and instead navigate to the next tab to the right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: set `workbench.editor.focusRecentEditorAfterClose` to `false`.